# why I can't use "gets function" after using "cin function" in dev c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
      char a[120];
      int b;

      cout<<"age : ";
      cin>>b;

      cout<<"Name : ";
      gets(a);

      cout<<"Name : "<<a<<endl;
      cout<<"age  : "<<b;
      cout<<endl;

      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

output :
age : 20 // I type 20 
Name: Name :                // it doesn't ask to type name.
age : 20
press any key to continue ...

But, if I use gets(a) first, it's ok.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
      char a[120];
      int b;

      cout<<"Name : ";
      gets(a);

      cout<<"age : ";
      cin>>b;

      cout<<"Name : "<<a<<endl;
      cout<<"age  : "<<b;
      cout<<endl;

      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

output :
Name  : John // I type John.
age   : 20 // I type 20.

Name  : John
age   : 20
Press any key to continue...

What happen to them ... Please Help ...

Comment: Note: The C++ headers are called <iostream>, <conio>, <stdio> and <string>.

Comment: @typ1232 You meant <conio.h> and <cstdio>

Comment: Never ever use `gets`! This is the one function that is so incredibly broken by design that it was actually **removed** from newer versions of the C standard. There is no way to use it safely. If you have to use C I/O, use `fgets(stdin, ...)`.

Comment: Update your environment and at least use [Orwell Dev-C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/), which uses a modern C++ compiler and MinGW-w64. Or use a better IDE. There are tons around.

Comment: Also: Don't use `system("pause")`. Make your IDE hold the console open or run your program directly in a console window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Avoid use functions from iostream and stdio together.**

However, your problem is caused by an additional `Enter`.

When you enters age and press enter, `cin` only comsumes the number.
The `Enter` is passed to `gets()` so it directly returns.

A fix could be

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    char a[120];
    int b;

    cout<<"age : ";
    cin>>b;

    cin.ignore();  //add this line to eat the enter

    cout<<"Name : "<<flush;
    gets(a);

    cout<<"Name : "<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"age  : "<<b;
    cout<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !It really works. But, I still don't understand why you add "flush".
It still works without flush . I was a little bit confuse . Could you explain me? Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure the "Name :" thing is printed out before `get(a);`. In this case it is useless so you can remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever book/internet tutorial you're learning from right now, throw it away. No, seriously. This code reads as if it was written in 1992. [Here is the list of books recommended by Stack Overflow community.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Also, if your Dev-C++ version is 4.9.9.2, I highly recommend an update - newer IDE will provide better editor, better debugger, and, (really important) better compiler. Better compiler will give you better error messages, and that is important when learning C++ (trust me on that, I know from experience) Common alternatives are: Visual C++, Code::Blocks or if you like Dev-C++, just upgrade to Orwell Dev-C++.

Let us fast forward to 2013 now.

**Warnings**

There are several jokes that can be reduced to "meh, i listen to errors not to warnings". They are wrong. 95% of warnings mean that the code is wrong. Since C++ is a tricky language, everyone should enable warnings in theirs IDEs (puzzles me why they are not enabled by default).

**Headers**

Introductions of namespaces to C++ means old headers are *deprecated*. This means they should not be used when writing new code.

The headers names are changed like this:

- builtin C++ headers don't have ".h" at the end. ("iostream.h" --> "iostream")
- Headers originated from C don't have ".h" at the end, also they are prefixed with "c" ("stdio.h" --> "cstdio")
- conio.h is neither builtin C header nor builtin C++ header, so the name stays like it was.

[Here is list of standard headers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)

**Strings**

C++ has a string type. `std::string`. It allows for simple string operations without hassle. Just `#include <string>` to use it.

```
string first_name = "John";
string surname = "Titor";
string full_name = first_name + " " + surname; //easy concatenation

//string a = "first" + " " + "name" //nasty surprise

string c = "first" + string(" ") + "name" //much better
//or using stringstream (#include <sstream>)
stringstream ss;
ss << "first" << " " << "name";
c = ss.str();
```

**gets()**

This function is impossible to use safely - it doesn't limit user input nor expands buffer. In your example code, someone could enter more than 120 characters and end up envoking *undefined behaviour*. This term is equivalent to math's undefined behaviour - anything can happen, including 1 being equal to 2. The `gets()` function was recently removed from C language altogether.
C++ has a safe alternative.

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);
```

**Proper declaration of main()**

```
int main()
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: [Here's a comprehensive list of C++ Standard Library headers.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) Other than that, +1. Also, I suggest using clang++, it features the most legible and useful messages IMO.

Comment: @DyP Your list better explains what each header is for. I'll add it in to my answer.